# Функция rand в цикле

Tags: c++, время, случайные-числа

```
double rnd()
{
    srand(time(0));
    return(rand() % 1000 / 1000.0);
}
```

Функцию выше вызываю в цикле, нужно совершить 1600 * 50000 прокручиваний. 
Все знакомы с функцией `time()`, цикл за секунду пробегает во много раз больше шагов, чем 1. В итоге получаю докучи одинаковых чисел.

Для решения моей задачи мне необходимы получать на каждом прокручивание случайное число (вероятность) какого-то события.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`srand(time(0));` нужно вызывать один раз в начале. Случайность будет нормальная.
Постоянный вызов `srand` случайность не улучшает.

**Дополнение**

Если очень сильно упростить эти две функции (очень сильно), то код будет выглядеть где-то так:

```
int seed = 0; // это начальное значение генератора
int gen = 0; // начальное значения рандома
int magick = 1234567; // это такая специальная магическая константа, я ее сам придумал:)
     // а вообще то есть целые исследования, которые определяют правильные константы
     // того же Кнута почитать можно

void srand(int s) {
  seed = s;
}

int rand() {
  return func(gen, seed);
}

int func(int g, int s) {
  // эта функция на базе предыдущего значения вычисляет новое.
  // главное, что нужно понимать, что при одних и тех же значениях аргументов,
  // результат будет один и тот же.
  // реализация, приведенная ниже - это один с возможных вариантов.
  return (s * magick + g) % 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Возникает вопрос - почему так сделано? Все очень просто. Сделать быстрый и качественный генератор достаточно сложно. Поэтому берут самые простые варианты. Усложнять подобные генераторы нет смысла - от этого их качество не улучшится, в лучшем случае останется таким же. Но обычно только ухудшается.

Ещё одна причина, по которой это сделано - удобство отладки. Ведь `seed` определяет всю последовательность. И если его задать одинаковым, то `rand` будет выдавать одни и те же последовательности.

Если нужна действительно случайная последовательность, то тут есть следующие варианты:

- купить специальное устройство, которое будет генерировать случайные числа. Вот например такое [USB-токен «iBank 2 Key»](http://bifit.ua/products/token/index.html). Первое, что нашлось в гугле:)
- собрать такое устройство самостоятельно - [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133320/). Там много интересного.
- купить специальный файл со случайными числами (да, такое продают. Я понимаю, что многие любители Линукса скажут, мол я с `/dev/random` сам нагенерю, но компании обещают хорошее качество.

Comment: Помогло, все так просто было что ли. 
Выходит наоборот: частый вызов случайность портит?

Comment: @Adrug, вызов srand задает первое число в цепочке псевдослучайных чисел, причем оно зависит только от входного аргумента srand. Поэтому вызов rand() после вызова srand(x) будет возвращать одно и то же число, если x фиксировано.

Answer (score 4):

Это - т.наз. "часто возникающая ошибка".

Если код программы содержит множественные попытки "перезапустить" генератор псевдослучайных чисел, используя в качестве seed-значения текущее значение времени, полученное через вызов `time(NULL)`

```
...
srand(time(NULL));
...
```

то может получиться так, что такие вызовы `srand` будут следовать друг за другом очень быстро. Так быстро, что `time(NULL)` будет возвращать одно и то же значение времени. Это приведет к тому, что генератор псевдослучайных чисел будет постоянно перезапускаться с указанием одного и того же seed-значения. В результате последующие вызовы `rand()` будут порождать одну и ту же псевдослучайную последовательность.

Например, вот такой код, будучи запущенным на выполнение, вероятнее всего выведет одну и ту же псевдослучайную последовательность два раза

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned n = 20; n > 0; --n) 
      printf("%d ", rand());
    printf("\n");  

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned n = 20; n > 0; --n) 
      printf("%d ", rand());
    printf("\n");  
}
```

Эта проблема также иногда рапортуется в следующем виде: "Под дебаггерром у меня в программе получаются разные случайные числа, а без дебаггера - одни и те же". Действительно, когда программа выполняется по шагам в интерактивном дебаггере, она выполняется "медленно" и между вызовами `srand` значение времени `time(NULL)` успевает измениться, что создает иллюзию того, что все работает "как задумано". Но стоит запустить программу в свободное выполнение, как проблема проявляется во всей красе.

Если вам нужен вызов `srand(time(NULL))` в вашей программе, то в большинстве случаев его достаточно сделать всего один-единственный раз на старте программы.