# Как сделать так, чтобы в переменная принимала каждый раз разные случайные значения после условного cin'a?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Прошу не бить. Начал учить плюсы где-то месяц-полтора назад, и решил склеить из (кхм) и палок простейший текстовый dungeon crawler. Зачем? Просто практика намного результативнее для меня, чем зубрежка.
Так вот, у нас есть определённый энкаунтер с противником. Пользователь вводит число для действия. Действия же условного врага я решил реализовать путем создания случайного значения переменной (c помощью ctime) и там уже на свичах сделать кейсы. Но в ходе написания я понял свою глупость, ведь когда интовая переменная принимает значение ранда (пр: int enemyAction = rand() % 3), она не меняет своего значения до конца программы, а мне нужно, чтобы после каждого условного cin'а пользователя значение переменной менялось на новое значение. Ну, или если такое невозможно реализовать таким способом, то есть другие? (Любой другой способ реализовать простейший энкаунтер).
Сразу хочу попросить прощения за глупый вопрос :(
Спасибо заранее!
P.s: Пример внизу - урезанная версия, чтобы было проще понять. Самое главное для меня - понять, как делать рандомные числа каждый раз. И ДА, я знаю, что goto - очень плохая практика, я потом переделаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int enemyHealth = 50;
    int enemyAttack = 10;
    int enemyAction = 0;
    nt container = 0;
    int act;
    int heroHealth = 100;
    int heroAttack = 15;
    bool defend = false;
    bool enemyDefend = false;
    bool enemyEvade = false;
    bool attacking = false;
    string name;
    cin >> name;
heroAct:
    cin >> act;
    while (enemyHealth > 0)
    {
        switch (act)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            if (enemyHealth > 0)
            {
                enemyHealth = enemyHealth - heroAttack;
            }

            cout << "\n Удар" << endl;
            if (enemyHealth <= 0)
            {
                cout << "\nПобеда!" << endl;
            }
            attacking = true;
            cout << "\nВраг. Здоровье: " << enemyHealth << " " << "Атака: " << enemyAttack << endl;
            cout << name + ". Здоровье: " << heroHealth << " " << "Атака: " << heroAttack << endl;
            cout << "1 - Атака; 2 - Защита;" << endl;
            goto spiderAct;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            cout << "Защита." << endl;
            defend = true;
            goto spiderAct;
        }
        }
    spiderAct:
        {
            int spiderAction = rand() % 3;
            switch (spiderAction)
            {
            case 1:
            {
                if (heroHealth > 0)
                {
                    heroHealth = heroHealth - enemyAttack;
                    cout << "\nУдар врага." << endl;
                    goto heroAct;
                }
                else if (defend == true)
                {
                    heroHealth = heroHealth - (enemyAttack / 2);
                    cout << "\nУдар врага с защитой." << endl;
                    goto heroAct;
                }


            }
            case 2:
            {
                enemyDefend = true;
                cout << "\nЗащита врага." << endl;
                goto heroAct;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                enemyEvade = true;
                cout << "\nУклонение врага." << endl;
                goto heroAct;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему нельзя вызывать `enemyAction = rand() % 3;` после каждого ввода из `cin`?

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Вроде-бы у вас всё рандомно. А переменную `enemyAction` вы вообще не используете. Только баг здесь увидел : `int spiderAction = ( rand() % 3 )` **+ 1** `;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, спасибо! У меня не работал рандом, потому что как раз не было прописано +1...

Answer (score 0):

`srand()` надо вызывать после каждой функции `rand()`.

В начале программы Вы ввели ключ рандомизации, после про него забыли. Однако, этот ключ может вывести только один рандомный ответ.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `srand() надо вызывать после каждой функции rand()` Нет, не нужно. Ответ неверен. См.: [Функция rand в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/320633).