# Ускорение выборки `srand(time(NULL));`

Tags: c++

есть рандом в диапазоне 0-8 (`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`)
на вход приходит условие что результат может быть только 1 и 2 или 5 и7 или все кроме 2 или вообще любое сочетание( не все 9 значений или все, главное не одно )
вопрос в том чтобы быстро рандом срабатывал (например! когда нужно вернуть 2 или 5 очень долго перебирает чтобы вернуть либо 5 либо 2)

```
  m02:   int rnd; srand(time(NULL)); rnd = rand() % 9;
if ((rnd == 0) || (rnd == 2) || (rnd == 6) || (rnd == 8))
    {return rnd;} else { goto m02; }
```

как заставить функцию работать быстрее, как в плюсах грамотно сделать. спасибо.

Comment: Для начала вынести `srand(time(NULL))` перед «циклом», а ещё лучше вызвать [один раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/320633) в начале работы программы. Возможно в рамках вашей задачи этого будет достаточно.

Comment: @wololo -спасибо тебе добрый человек

Comment: А вообще, т.к. множество генерируемых значений мало (не больше девяти элементов), то можно все необходимые значения поместить в массив `int arr[5] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7};`, и затем возвращать случайный элемент данного массива: `return arr[rand()%5];`

Answer (score 6):

В вашем коде есть неприятное место:

```
srand(time(NULL));
rnd = rand() % 9;
```

Этот код в течении одной секунды выдаёт одно и то же значение. `time(NULL)` выдаёт текущее время с разрешением в одну секунду. `srand` сбрасывает случайный генератор, затем вы спрашиваете первое случайное число. Если оно вас устраивает, то в течении секунды вы будете его выдавать снова и снова. Если число вас не устраивает, цикл будет ждать конца секунды. После чего процесс повторится.

Вам нужна функция в которую вы передадите массив цифр (вариантов для выбора). Функция выберет один из элементов случайным образом и вернёт. Все достаточно быстро, числа будут настолько случайные насколько это возможно.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Sampler {
public:
    int get_random(const std::vector<int> &values) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(0, values.size() - 1);
        return values[distrib(gen)];
    }
private:
    std::mt19937 gen;
};
 
int main() {
    const std::vector<int> digits = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    Sampler s;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        std::cout << s.get_random(digits) << '\n';

    }
}
```

Десять миллионов случайных цифр в секунду:

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 slow-random.cpp
>
> $ time ./a.out | wc -l
> 10000000
>
> real  0m0.857s
> user  0m0.872s
> sys   0m0.024s
> ```

Comment: Ну, раз вы удалили комментарий, перенесу и я свою сюда. Мне кажется, что эта неслучайность младших битов сильно преувеличена. Вот сейчас прогнал на VC++ по хи-квадрату распределение `rand()%5` (о котором вы писали) со значимостью 0.01 — говорит, что отвергать гипотезу о равномерном распределении не надо :)

Comment: @Harry ,  а `%4` сразу будет хуже. Проверите?

Comment: Вот числа для %4 — 10000 попыток: 2581 2429 2462 2528. Опять все считать не хочется, но исходя из того, что для 5 разброс был, по сути, не больше — 1959 2007 2021 1986 2027 — то не думаю, что тут что-то принципиально изменится...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо. Я тестировал распределение пар значений. Генератор по модулю не хуже чем равномерное распределение из стандартной библиотеки. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Думается мне, что говорить о случайности  тех или иных бит нельзя в отрыве от алгоритма, который в своих недрах использует `std::rand`, а он стандартом языка не специфицируется . Полагаю, в своём ответе вы подразумевали, что подлежащий алгоритм есть линейный конгруэнтный метод, и обычно так оно и есть. Если [верить Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use), библиотечные реализации зачастую не такие наивные, как можно было бы подумать на первый взгляд — они пытаются разными способами обойти недостатки ЛК метода...

Comment: В частности, нередко используются только старшие биты генерируемых значений. Но, повторюсь, алгоритм `std::rand` не специфицируется стандартом, поэтому и полагаться в общем случае на качество генерируемых им значений нельзя. Интересно, есть ли реализации `std::rand` не основанные на линейном конгруэнтном методе? Что с качеством младших/старших бит, генерируемых `std::mt19937`?

Comment: Я делал тесты на распределение пар бит для младшего бита rand, старшего бита rand и вихря Мерсенна с равномерным распределением. Всё примерно одинаково.

Comment: Нашёл исходный код `rand`. Линейный конгруэнтный метод. Младший бит выбрасывается в одном из вариантов: [Chucking least random bit](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/random_r.c.html#376).

Comment: Так или иначе мои знания устарели. Биты нынче куда лучше стали.

Comment: `подлежащий алгоритм есть линейный конгруэнтный метод, и обычно так оно и есть` Я не прав. Например,  glibc использует некую вариацию регистра сдвига с линейной обратной связью (_The random number generation technique is a linear feedback shift register approach_). См.: [glibc rand function implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18634079).

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите в самом деле быстро?

Тогда упростите вывод результата, насколько возможно (переход от `printf()` к `putchar()` дает выигрыш в 5 раз)
(ну, и берите несколько маленьких чисел из одного вызова `random()` (улучшает время вдвое))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int d[9] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

  /* 1.  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    printf("%d\n", d[random() % 9]);

    avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -O3
    avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time ./a.out | wc -l
    10000000

    real        0m0.568s
    user        0m0.582s
    sys 0m0.025s

  */

  /* 2.
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    putchar(d[random() % 9]+'0'), putchar('\n');

    avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -O3
    avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time ./a.out | wc -l
    10000000

    real        0m0.103s
    user        0m0.132s
    sys 0m0.013s

  */


  // А вот это в самом деле быстро
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000 / 5; i++) {

    int r = random();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++, r >> 5)
      putchar(d[(r & 0x1f) % 9] + '0'), putchar('\n');
  }
  /*
    avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c -O3
    avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time ./a.out | wc -l
    10000000

    real        0m0.064s
    user        0m0.056s
    sys 0m0.049s
  */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: По вашему цель ТС - писать случайные числа десятками миллионов в консоль?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, и вы не поняли? Безусловно, я преследовал 2 цели 1) Продемонстрировать, как использовать **один вызов** для получения сразу нескольких случайных чисел (ускорение -- **вот цель ТС**) 2) Реальное влияние уровня абстракций на производительность конкретной задачи (ТС пока может и не поймет, но вдруг что-то в его голове отложится) / И еще (скорее к пункту 2) -- показать то же самое  автору предыдущего ответа (в том, что он поймет, я не сомневаюсь)

Comment: Потребность в ускорении у тс возникла от абсурдно неэффективного _алгоритма_ получения случайных чисел. Выигранная вами сотня миллисекунд на ускорении ввода/вывода миллиона чисел - ничто до тех пор пока генерация очередного числа занимает целую секунду.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, вы опять не читаете всю тему (и даже не анализируете вывод time в комментариях в коде), и в результате  ничего не понимаете (или считаете, что настоящая цель любого ответа -- это ответ на конкретно заданный вопрос ТС)

Comment: Тот не понимает, этот понимает, а вот тот может быть поймёт когда-нибудь. Интересная у вас позиция :) Добавьте анализ вывода time в ответ, чтобы всем было понятно, как ускорение вывода сможет помочь, если вызов random() занимает целую секунду.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, опять мимо (в данной программе **основное время тратится не на random()**). Оптимизация вывода дает 5-кратное ускорение, а сокращение вызовов `random()` в 5 раз лишь двукратное (кстати, на практике это немало). В целом, ускорение (относительно второго (канонически крестового)  ответа) на порядок. Еще раз повторяю, внутренняя мотивация моего ответа именно в такой демонстрации (и да, очевидно, что это не для всех)

Comment: В программе ТС основное время тратиться **именно на "random"**. Еще раз повторяю, генератор случайных чисел ТС абсурдно неэффективен, и никакое ускорение вывода это не исправит.

Comment: В вопросе ТС не было вывода случайных чисел на консоль.

Comment: Вариант с пятью цифрами за раз порождает цифры с неравномерным распределением.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, почему? Если все 31 бит в числе случайны (и я надеюсь, равномерно), то и получаемые 5-битные числа (насколько я понимаю) будут с тем же равномерным распределением. / Что же касается вывода на консоль, так это повтор вашего примера

Comment: Проблема в том что 32 не делится на девять нацело.

Comment: А 2^31 делится?

Comment: Они все страдают от этого недостатка. Но в случае 2^31 разница в вероятностях очень мала. А в случае 32 вполне заметна.

Comment: Ok, учту. И где, по вашему мнению, проходит граница, как ее определить? Скажем 10 бит это достаточно?

Comment: 32 = 4 нуля, ..., 4 четверки, 3 пятерки, ... 3 восьмерки. Вероятность нуля - 4/32, вероятность восьмерки - 3/32. Отличается на четверть.

Comment: 1024 - вероятность нуля 114/1024, вероятность восьмерки 113/1024. Разница чуть меньше процента.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132076/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and-avp).