# Насколько плох метод rand()%N для генерации случайных чисел в небольшом диапазоне?

Tags: c++, математика, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

Собственно, все сказано в заголовке.
Часто утверждают, что этот метод плох, особенно **для небольших значений `N`**. Но хотелось бы понять, *насколько* он плох?
Можно ли им пользоваться или это категорически неприемлемо?

Comment: Мне казалось, что он плох для *больших* значений `N`, так как `rand` возвращает числа в диапазоне от 0 до RAND_MAX, который в той же VS всего 32767.

Comment: Я в C++ не силён, но с математической точки зрения, если rand генерирует равномерное распределение на отрезке [0, 32767], то если взять N = 20000, то у числа 1 вероятность выпадения примерно в два раза выше чем у числа 19000. Что довольно плохо говорит о распределении.

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/ ну и тут написано «makes lower numbers slightly more likely», т.е. маленькие числа (1) выпадают чаще чем большие (19000). Т.е. нормальной результат получается если N мало или степень двойки.

Comment: _Implementation-defined behavior_... Алгоритм генерации значений `std::rand` отдан на откуп конкретным реализациям. Обычно это линейный конгруэнтный генератор. Опасения относительно качества чисел вида `rand()%N`  при малых `N` вызваны тем, что написать линейный конгруэнтный генератор, производящий числа с плохим распределением в младших битах в общем-то [не сложно](https://ideone.com/IPR9Ho). Можно ли доверять реализации `std::rand()` в вашем любимом %CompilerName% или нет... это уже решать вам.

Comment: @user7860670 Навеяно [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1357059/195342), при ответе на который было сказано о плохом распределении именно для *малых* значений.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вас, наверное, удивит, но `uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 19999);` в VC++ 2019 дает точно тот же результат — разницу в 2 раза :) Собственно, именно поэтому я и написал в ответе *"для каждого конкретного компилятора я бы проверял его"* — потому что опять же, нигде не сказано, что `RAND_MAX` — это обязательно 32768. Но спасибо за то, что заставили подумать о прощупывании разных генераторов...

Comment: Ну криворукие 

Comment: @AlexeyTen Это я немного поспешил — в том плане, что первые 2 запуска показали очевидный перекос в сторону 1. Но если позапускать побольше и количество чисел попросить миллионы — то все устаканивается. Но все же как-нибудь по свободе займусь, потестирую их генераторы. Надо же знать, с чем дело имеешь :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для проверки гипотезы о том, что для небольших значений `N` происходит перекос значений `rand()%N` набросал простенькую программу, которая применяет хи-квадрат критерий для разных значений `N` и разного количества генерируемых значений.

Саму программу можно найти [тут](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/5d90f7e4bf21fb03656e00b6b39188f7adb305e9/exper/uniform.cpp), а результаты ее работы (VC++ 2019) — ниже.

Как видите, по сути оба способа — и старый `rand()%N`, и новый `uniform_int_distribution` + стандартный генератор — дают весьма похожие результаты.

Гипотеза о равномерном распределении на нарушается почти нигде, а если случайно и отвергается — то с равным успехом в обоих случаях.

Таким образом, как мне кажется, отвергать указанный способ не стоит. Но для каждого конкретного компилятора я бы проверял его этой программой, чтобы убедиться в том, что это и в самом деле так.

```
Values count = 10
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      3.60  ok          0.40  ok  
 3     5.9      2.60  ok          3.20  ok  
 4     7.8      2.00  ok          3.60  ok  
 5     9.5      3.00  ok          4.00  ok  
 6    11.1      3.20  ok          4.40  ok  
 7    12.6      6.80  ok          8.20  ok  
 8    14.1      9.20  ok          4.40  ok  
 9    15.5     15.20  ok          0.80  ok  


Values count = 100
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.36  ok          0.00  ok  
 3     5.9      1.46  ok          1.34  ok  
 4     7.8      1.36  ok          0.56  ok  
 5     9.5      1.90  ok          3.70  ok  
 6    11.1      2.72  ok          2.12  ok  
 7    12.6      5.56  ok          2.62  ok  
 8    14.1      8.32  ok          4.96  ok  
 9    15.5      7.82  ok          7.10  ok  


Values count = 1000
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.48  ok          0.48  ok  
 3     5.9      0.60  ok          0.51  ok  
 4     7.8      4.47  ok         10.07  fail
 5     9.5      3.02  ok          1.75  ok  
 6    11.1      3.92  ok          3.48  ok  
 7    12.6      9.99  ok          6.71  ok  
 8    14.1     19.12  fail        9.94  ok  
 9    15.5      5.91  ok          8.90  ok  


Values count = 10000
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.29  ok          1.64  ok  
 3     5.9      0.35  ok          0.19  ok  
 4     7.8      3.02  ok          3.10  ok  
 5     9.5      5.93  ok          7.44  ok  
 6    11.1      3.42  ok          3.60  ok  
 7    12.6      6.59  ok          3.97  ok  
 8    14.1      4.85  ok          4.31  ok  
 9    15.5      5.74  ok         10.13  ok  


Values count = 100000
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.18  ok          0.13  ok  
 3     5.9      0.21  ok          0.24  ok  
 4     7.8      2.57  ok          0.57  ok  
 5     9.5      0.55  ok          2.89  ok  
 6    11.1      4.19  ok          1.54  ok  
 7    12.6      2.71  ok         11.04  ok  
 8    14.1     15.91  fail       11.78  ok  
 9    15.5      5.87  ok          4.27  ok
```

Для полной самодостаточности код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

using namespace std;


double Xi[20][2] = // For \alpha = 0.10 && 0.05
{
    {  2.7,  3.8 },         // 1
    {  4.6,  5.9 },
    {  6.3,  7.8 },
    {  7.8,  9.5 },
    {  9.2, 11.1 },
    { 10.6, 12.6 },
    { 12.0, 14.1 },
    { 13.4, 15.5 },
    { 14.7, 16.9 },
    { 16.0, 18.3 },
    { 17.3, 19.7 },
    { 18.5, 21.0 },
    { 19.8, 22.4 },
    { 21.1, 23.7 },
    { 22.3, 25.0 },
    { 23.5, 26.3 },
    { 24.8, 27.6 },
    { 26.0, 28.9 },
    { 27.2, 30.1 },
    { 40.3, 43.8 }   // > 30...
};


default_random_engine g(random_device{}());


void Experiment(int N, int Count = 10000)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, N-1);
    vector<int> r(N), u(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    {
        r[rand()%N]++;
        u[dis(g)]++;
    }
    double rs = 0, us = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        double d = double(r[i])/Count - 1./N;
        rs += d*d;
        d = double(u[i])/Count - 1./N;
        us += d*d;
    }

    rs = rs * Count * N;
    us = us * Count * N;

    double xi = (N < 20) ? Xi[N-2][1] : Xi[19][1];


    cout << setw(2) << N << "   " << fixed << setprecision(1)
        << setw(5) << xi << "   " << setprecision(2)
        << setw(7) << rs << ( rs < xi ? "  ok  " : "  fail")
        << "     "
        << setw(7) << us << ( us < xi ? "  ok  " : "  fail")
        << endl;
}



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int Count = 10; Count <= 100000; Count *= 10)
    {
        cout << "\n\nValues count = " << Count << "\n";
        cout << " N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform\n";
        cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";
        for(int N = 2; N < 10; ++N) Experiment(N,Count);
    }

}
```

Comment: У Кнута было в третьей главе подробное исследование, и в частности говорилось о проблемах с младшими битами линейных конгруэнтных генераторов (это как раз для случая, когда N — степень двойки). И там было много всяческих тестов на «случайность».

Comment: @user7860670 Если протухнет gitlab :) Не хотелось делать огромный ответ, но вы правы...

Comment: @VladD,  у меня в `Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-91-generic #102~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 11 14:46:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia \n \l` весь вывод **ok**. Лень проверять, но помнится в коде `random()` из bsd (The University of California, Berkeley) младшие биты как-то особым образом тасовались (видимо они читали коллегу из Стенфорда -))

Comment: @avp Вот еще один тест с gcc - https://ideone.com/fdYYLS

Comment: Кстати да, стоит ещё проверить распределение при N степенях двойки

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ну, по ссылке до 32 данные есть...

Comment: @Harry, да, у меня тоже `fail` появились. Что интересно, без оптимизации и с -O3 в разных местах (как-то настораживает...)

Comment: @avp А вы при проверке генератор одинаково инициализировали (или не инициализировали)? Оно же при каждом запуске по-новому работает...

Comment: @Harry, тогда понятно (я запускал код как есть, теперь вижу `srand(time(0));`).

Comment: @avp а еще и `default_random_engine g(random_device{}());`

Answer (score 9):

Стандарт языка не специфицирует алгоритм, используемый функцией [std::rand()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) для генерации случайных чисел, поэтому в общем случае, не зная ни подлежащего алгоритма, ни *решаемой задачи*, я бы не стал делать поспешных выводов о качестве случайных чисел, генерируемых функцией `rand()`.

Для примера рассмотрим пару реализаций функции `rand()`.

#### glibc

Документация [man 3 rand](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) утверждает, что функция `rand` использует тот же генератор случайных чисел, что и `random()`, поэтому младшие биты генерируемых значений такие же случайные, как и старшие:

> The versions of `rand()` and `srand()` in the Linux C Library use the same random number generator as `random(3)` and `srandom(3)`, so the lower-order bits should be as random as the higher-order bits.

Документация [man 3 random](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) поясняет, что в качестве алгоритма генерации используется *«nonlinear additive feedback random number generator»*. Хотя конкретные детали не уточняются. Только сказано, что с помощью функции `initstate()` можно установить размер внутреннего состояния генератора на `8`, `32`, `64`, `128`, или даже `128` байт.

Чтобы понять, что конкретно делает `random()` можно посмотреть

- [Исходный код функции](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/random_r.c) (там в комментариях метод генерации называют *«linear feedback shift register approach, employing trinomials (since there are fewer terms to sum up that way)»*.)
- Вопрос на enSO: [glibc rand function implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18634079).
- [Статью](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/random/) за авторством Peter Selinger: The GLIBC random number generator.

Изучение приведённых источников показывает, что документация тактично умалчивает, что если с помощью `initstate()` установить размер внутреннего состояния на восемь байт, то вместо хитрого генератора с хорошими младшими битами будет использоваться [линейный конгруэнтный генератор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4) с не очень хорошими младшими битами. ​

[Программа](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0023dcfbe091df9d):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t state_size = 8;
    char state[state_size] = {};
    unsigned int seed = 1;
    
    initstate(seed, state, state_size);
    
    for (int N = 2; N <= 8; N *= 2)
    {
        cout << "N: " << N << "    ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                cout << rand() % N << " ";
            cout << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

И симпатичные случайные последовательности, которые генерирует `rand() % N` для некоторых `N`:

```
N: 2    0 1   0 1   0 1   0 1   0 1   0 1   0 1   0 1   

N: 4    2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   2 3 0 1   

N: 8    6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1   6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1
```

Предложенный @Harry в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1357116) хи-квадрат критерий данные последовательности успешно проходят:

```
Values count = 10
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.00  ok          1.60  ok  
 3     5.9      0.80  ok          0.80  ok  
 4     7.8      0.40  ok          0.40  ok  
 5     9.5      8.00  ok          8.00  ok  
 6    11.1      5.60  ok          3.20  ok  
 7    12.6      6.80  ok         12.40  ok  
 8    14.1      1.20  ok          9.20  ok  
 9    15.5      4.40  ok         11.60  ok  


Values count = 100
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.00  ok          1.44  ok  
 3     5.9      0.32  ok          0.74  ok  
 4     7.8      0.00  ok          1.68  ok  
 5     9.5      5.80  ok          0.70  ok  
 6    11.1      5.84  ok          6.80  ok  
 7    12.6      2.34  ok          4.02  ok  
 8    14.1      0.16  ok          4.80  ok  
 9    15.5     24.74  fail        6.74  ok  


Values count = 1000
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.00  ok          0.32  ok  
 3     5.9      1.09  ok          1.23  ok  
 4     7.8      0.00  ok          6.37  ok  
 5     9.5      2.79  ok          1.27  ok  
 6    11.1      1.62  ok          2.90  ok  
 7    12.6      6.87  ok          2.34  ok  
 8    14.1      0.00  ok          8.00  ok  
 9    15.5      7.64  ok          9.17  ok  


Values count = 10000
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.00  ok          0.18  ok  
 3     5.9      2.19  ok          0.76  ok  
 4     7.8      0.00  ok          4.75  ok  
 5     9.5      8.32  ok          6.32  ok  
 6    11.1      2.56  ok          0.48  ok  
 7    12.6      2.83  ok          3.89  ok  
 8    14.1      0.00  ok          2.38  ok  
 9    15.5      4.97  ok          7.56  ok  


Values count = 100000
 N  xi(0.05)    rand()%N          uniform
-----------------------------------------
 2     3.8      0.00  ok          0.66  ok  
 3     5.9      2.62  ok          4.50  ok  
 4     7.8      0.00  ok          1.61  ok  
 5     9.5     15.34  fail        2.23  ok  
 6    11.1      1.73  ok          5.98  ok  
 7    12.6      2.51  ok          9.07  ok  
 8    14.1      0.00  ok          6.20  ok  
 9    15.5      8.17  ok          8.45  ok
```

#### MSVCRT

vc++ также использует линейный конгруэнтный генератор ([Understanding the algorithm of Visual C++'s rand() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6793065)). Для улучшения свойств генерируемой последовательности часть битов отбрасывается. Из 32 битов получаемого значения отбрасываются 16 младших и один старший (`(val >> 16) & 0x7fff`). Это немного удлиняет периоды последовательностей, формируемых младшими разрядами.

Сформируем изображение высотой `256` пикселей и шириной `image_width` пикселей, где цвет каждого пикселя задаётся целым числом из отрезка `[0; 255]` по следующему алгоритму:

```
const int N = ...;
const int image_width = ...;
for (int row = 0; row < 256; ++row)
    for (int col = 0; col < image_width; ++col)
        image[row][col] = std::rand() % N * (255 / (N-1));
```

В результате получились следующие изображения.

`N = 8; image_width = 509;`

[image: rand()%N; N = 8; image_width = 509;]

`N = 4; image_width = 511;`

[image: rand()%N; N = 4; image_width = 511;]

`N = 2; image_width = 512;`

[image: rand()%N; N = 2; image_width = 512;]

Для сравнения, если в приведённом коде заменить `std::rand()` на `std::mt19937`, то получаются такие изображения:

`N = 8; image_width = 509;`

[image: mt()%N; N = 8; image_width = 509;]

`N = 4; image_width = 511;`

[image: mt()%N; N = 4; image_width = 511;]

`N = 2; image_width = 512;`

[image: mt()%N; N = 2; image_width = 512;]

Comment: Ни в коем случае не как критика! просто интересно было бы посмотреть на реальную задачу, где это отличие приводит к... ну, пусть не к неверным, но хотя бы существенно отличающимся результатам. Кстати, еще один в принципе интересный вопрос — это наличие автокорреляции. Еще раз — прошу не рассматривать этот комментарий как критику.

Comment: @Harry, не стесняйтесь, если что-то не нравится, критикуйте. Ну, генерация изображений с шумом — чем не практическая задача? Хочется получить случайное изображение, а получается [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LEf4.png). Ладно, другой пример — [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/274253/). Там правда речь о JavaScript, но суть та же.

Comment: Кратко: получали случайные числа таким кодом `floor(random() * 64)`. Оказалось, что из-за некачественной реализации `random`, такое преобразование использует только часть битов внутреннего состояния генератора. Причём имеющую очень _малый период_ (как и здесь `rand() % N`), что привело к частым коллизиям при генерации идентификаторов. Прочитав статью ([англ. оригинал](https://medium.com/@betable/tifu-by-using-math-random-f1c308c4fd9d)), разработчики v8 сочли малый период генератора достаточной проблемой, чтобы [переписать](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random) реализацию `Math.random()`.

Comment: Э нет, это не метод `%`, а умножение, да еще и на 64 — очевидно, что 6 младших битов нулевые. Тут все понятно...

Comment: @Harry, там не просто 6 младших битов нулевые. Там итоговый результат определялся ровно шестью битами. Также  как и метод `% 64` берёт ровно шесть битов. Да, `% 64` берёт младшие 6 битов, а `* 64` взяло старшие 6 битов. Но вот какая штука: из-за некачественного алгоритма 6 старших битов имеют _малый период_. Точно также Сишный `rand()` может давать значения, у которых шесть младших битов имеют малый период. Замени они свой метод на Сишный `rand() % 64`, то получили бы ту же проблему.

Comment: Кстати, лично я еще задолго до всех этих `<random>` пользовался своими... в смысле, [Кнутовыми :)  генераторами](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/Rand.cpp).